# Results from C# JSON-Deserialization to String

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I used json2csharp to generate functions and classes but I am a bloody newbie. What I want is using the Data from the JSON Array and display it in a Textbox.

Here is the Code:

```
 public class Sent_SMS
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
        public string smslog_id { get; set; }
        public string queue { get; set; }
        public string to { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Sent_SMS> data { get; set; }
        public object error_string { get; set; }
        public int timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public void doSendSMS()
    {
        /* API URLs */

        APIURL_Send = "http://ipadressofgateway/playsms/index.php?app=ws&op=pv&h=" + apikey + "&u=" + username + "&to=" + receiver_number + "&msg=" + message; // Sending Message



        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = wc.DownloadString(APIURL_Send);
            var SMS_Log = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            richTextBox3.Text = "SMS has been sent to:" + SMS_Log.data.to + "Status is:" + SMS_Log.data.status;
        }

        }
```

But of course.. this does not work cause "SMS_Log.data.to" and "SMS_Log.data.status" is not correct. How to do this right?

Regards

Comment: `Data` is a `List<Sent_SMS>`. Are you sure you're sending a single SMS or multiple ones?

Comment: `RootObject.data` is a `List`. You need to iterate over that, or take the first element if you're sure it's there.

Comment: could you please share your josn response?

Comment: When I want to get the String from the Object  error_string .. what to do? JSON-Response is: "{"status":"ERR","error":"201","error_string":"destination number or message is empty","timestamp":1432043513}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure there is always exactly one SMS in the response, then change your code to:

```
richTextBox3.Text = "SMS has been sent to:" + SMS_Log.data[0].to + "Status is:" + SMS_Log.data[0].status;
```

Otherwise, I'd go for a solution like this:

```
var text = "";
foreach (var sms in SMS_Log.data) {
    text += "SMS has been sent to:" + sms.to + "Status is:" + sms.status + "\n";
}
richTextBox3.Text = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

SMS_Log.data is a list of Sent_SMS instances, so you'd have to iterate through that list to get each individual message's data.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<SMS_Log.data.Count();i++)
{
     richTextBox3.Text = "SMS has been sent to:" + SMS_Log.data[i].to + "Status     is:" + SMS_Log.data[i].status;
}
```

Though this would set only the last element as your TextBlock text. Would recommend you to add these into a new List and set this list as a source of **GridView** or **ListView**